# Guava Sets intersection(HashSet1, HashSet2) compares by hash or by value?

Tags: guava, hashset

When using Guava Sets to come up with the intersection of two `HashSet`s, how does it determine that two elements are identical? By their value or by their hash?

**== Update ==**

Looking at the source code of [java.util.HashSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.contains%28java.lang.Object%29), I realize that `contains()` actually calls `containsKey()` to do the comparison:

[image: HashSet.contains]

Comment: Hashes are never, ever used to determine equality. That's not their goal. Their goal, in a hash-based collection, is to reduce the number of potentially equal candidates.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for this clarification. Please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are never, ever used to determine equality. That's not their goal. Their goal, in a hash-based collection, is to reduce the number of potentially equal candidates.

`intersection()` returns a view over two sets, so it completely delegates the equality tests to the underlyong two Sets.

Comment: I just confirmed and verified by stepping through the code, that HashSet.contains() actually calls [HashSet.containsKey()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java) to determine equality. How does that coincide with above clarification?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no containsKey method in HashSet(). There is a contains() method. And this contains() method uses equals() to test equality.

Comment: Please look at the link in my comment. You can find there containsKey method in HashSet().  AFAICT.

Comment: No, there is not. Bu this is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: I updated my original post with a screenshot from the link I included. It is possible that I do not understand that redirect to `map.containsKey()`. Isn't `HashCode()` used as the key in a `HashSet()`? Your explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: The object you add to a HashSet serves as a key in the underlying HashMap used by the HashSet. So HashSet.contains(o) calls HashMap.containsKey(o). HashMap.containsKey() uses the hashCode of the object to find the bucket where the object is stored. That reduces the number of potentially equal objects in the set. Once the bucket is found (which typically contains 0 or 1 element, but could contain more), each object in the bucket is compared to the object passed to contains[Key](), and this comparison ultimetely uses equals() to know if the objects are equal.

Comment: As you can see from the documentation of the method in your screenshot, objects are compared with equals: *returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))*. hashCode() is never used to determine equality, because two non equal objects may have the same hashCode(). But it is used to reduce the number of candidates because two equal objects MUST have the same hashCode.